# Select2 choosing all options from filtered list for multiple selection

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-select2

Using the select2 plugin for jQuery on my select dropdown allows me to type and find partial matches quickly.  However if I wanted to grab all partial matches I'd have to click one, type the filter again, click the next, etc.  It gets tedious quickly.  Instead what I'd like to do is type the first few characters then select all of the FILTERED options.

For example, if I had a list of every state in the US and I typed "New" I would see "New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York".  I'd like a way to select all 4 without having to click each one.

Here's a jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/myingling/xv7bzqek/4/

```
<select name='state' id='state' multiple='multiple'>
                    <option value='null'> - Please Select - </option>
                    <option value='AL'>Alabama</option>
                    <option value='AK'>Alaska</option>
                    <option value='AZ'>Arizona</option>
                    <option value='AR'>Arkansas</option>
                    <option value='CA'>California</option>
                    <option value='CO'>Colorado</option>
                    <option value='CT'>Connecticut</option>
                    <option value='DE'>Delaware</option>
                    <option value='DC'>District Of Columbia</option>
                    <option value='FL'>Florida</option>
                    <option value='GA'>Georgia</option>
                    <option value='HI'>Hawaii</option>
                    <option value='ID'>Idaho</option>
                    <option value='IL'>Illinois</option>
                    <option value='IN'>Indiana</option>
                    <option value='IA'>Iowa</option>
                    <option value='KS'>Kansas</option>
                    <option value='KY'>Kentucky</option>
                    <option value='LA'>Louisiana</option>
                    <option value='ME'>Maine</option>
                    <option value='MD'>Maryland</option>
                    <option value='MA'>Massachusetts</option>
                    <option value='MI'>Michigan</option>
                    <option value='MN'>Minnesota</option>
                    <option value='MS'>Mississippi</option>
                    <option value='MO'>Missouri</option>
                    <option value='MT'>Montana</option>
                    <option value='NE'>Nebraska</option>
                    <option value='NV'>Nevada</option>
                    <option value='NH'>New Hampshire</option>
                    <option value='NJ'>New Jersey</option>
                    <option value='NM'>New Mexico</option>
                    <option value='NY'>New York</option>
                    <option value='NC'>North Carolina</option>
                    <option value='ND'>North Dakota</option>
                    <option value='OH'>Ohio</option>
                    <option value='OK'>Oklahoma</option>
                    <option value='OR'>Oregon</option>
                    <option value='PA'>Pennsylvania</option>
                    <option value='PR'>Puerto Rico</option>
                    <option value='RI'>Rhode Island</option>
                    <option value='SC'>South Carolina</option>
                    <option value='SD'>South Dakota</option>
                    <option value='TN'>Tennessee</option>
                    <option value='TX'>Texas</option>
                    <option value='UT'>Utah</option>
                    <option value='VT'>Vermont</option>
                    <option value='VA'>Virginia</option>
                    <option value='WA'>Washington</option>
                    <option value='WV'>West Virginia</option>
                    <option value='WI'>Wisconsin</option>
                    <option value='WY'>Wyoming</option>
</select>
<input type='button' id='all_visible' value='Select Visible' />
<script>
    jQuery('#state').select2();

    jQuery('#all_visible').click(function() {
         var visible = null; // TODO: how do we grab the filtered list?
         jQuery('#state').val(visible).trigger('change');
    });
</script>
```

Is there a way to do this?  The select2 documentation shows how to programatically select a SINGLE option, but not en-mass from their own filtered list.  There are plenty of other answers out there for selecting ALL options, but that would include the ones which are hidden by the filter (ex: California).

Sample mock:
[image]

Comment: What do you plan that the usage (UX) will be here? When you click on the button outside of the Selec2 - the select2 will automatically closed, because it loose focus.

Comment: Could add a button to select2 element itself?  The real-world use case is someone has a list of accounts, many of them belong to the same company (ex: "Acme Software", "Acme Shipping", "Acme Logicistics").  Instead of making them type "Acme" 3 times and click each one, filtering down to the 3 Acme businesses (as typing in a select2 does already) and then clicking a button which would choose all visible items.

Comment: Sample mock: https://i.snipboard.io/BGIsMp.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried getting the filtered visible values from the select dropdown. select2 plugin stores all the plugin data in the **data()** object. Here you can the results from **$("#select").data()**.

All you have to do is iterate over the filtered result elements **(li tag)** in the data object and trigger **mouseup** event for all those results elements.

Try below working example.

```html
<html>

<head>
   
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
    
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css">

    <style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">

    </style>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#state').select2();
            
            $('#all_visible').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var visible = null; // TODO: how do we grab the filtered list?
             //   $('#state').val(visible).trigger('change');

                // Get the data object of state dropdown
                var filteredValues = [];
                var select2Holder = $('#state').data(); 

                if (select2Holder && select2Holder.select2) {
                    // Find the $results object
                    var results = select2Holder.select2.$results;
                    if (results) {
                      //  var resultNode$ = $(results[0]);
                      //  console.log(resultNode$);
                        
                        if ($(results[0]) && $(results[0]).children().length > 0) {
                            $(results[0]).children().each(function(index, node) {
                               
                                var selectedValue;
                                // Get the option value from attribute
                                var id = $(node).attr('id');
                                // id attribute will be like this 'select2-state-result-x3b0-NH'
                                // split the id attribute using "-" and get last value
                                var arr  = id.split('-');
                                if (arr && arr.length > 0) {
                                  selectedValue = arr[arr.length -1 ];
                                  filteredValues.push(selectedValue);
                                }

                                $(node).trigger('mouseup');
                              
                            })
                          
                        }
                        
                    }

                }
            });
        })
    </script>

  
</head>

<body >
    <select name='state' id='state' multiple='multiple'>
        <option value='null'> - Please Select - </option>
        <option value='AL'>Alabama</option>
        <option value='AK'>Alaska</option>
        <option value='AZ'>Arizona</option>
        <option value='AR'>Arkansas</option>
        <option value='CA'>California</option>
        <option value='CO'>Colorado</option>
        <option value='CT'>Connecticut</option>
        <option value='DE'>Delaware</option>
        <option value='DC'>District Of Columbia</option>
        <option value='FL'>Florida</option>
        <option value='GA'>Georgia</option>
        <option value='HI'>Hawaii</option>
        <option value='ID'>Idaho</option>
        <option value='IL'>Illinois</option>
        <option value='IN'>Indiana</option>
        <option value='IA'>Iowa</option>
        <option value='KS'>Kansas</option>
        <option value='KY'>Kentucky</option>
        <option value='LA'>Louisiana</option>
        <option value='ME'>Maine</option>
        <option value='MD'>Maryland</option>
        <option value='MA'>Massachusetts</option>
        <option value='MI'>Michigan</option>
        <option value='MN'>Minnesota</option>
        <option value='MS'>Mississippi</option>
        <option value='MO'>Missouri</option>
        <option value='MT'>Montana</option>
        <option value='NE'>Nebraska</option>
        <option value='NV'>Nevada</option>
        <option value='NH'>New Hampshire</option>
        <option value='NJ'>New Jersey</option>
        <option value='NM'>New Mexico</option>
        <option value='NY'>New York</option>
        <option value='NC'>North Carolina</option>
        <option value='ND'>North Dakota</option>
        <option value='OH'>Ohio</option>
        <option value='OK'>Oklahoma</option>
        <option value='OR'>Oregon</option>
        <option value='PA'>Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value='PR'>Puerto Rico</option>
        <option value='RI'>Rhode Island</option>
        <option value='SC'>South Carolina</option>
        <option value='SD'>South Dakota</option>
        <option value='TN'>Tennessee</option>
        <option value='TX'>Texas</option>
        <option value='UT'>Utah</option>
        <option value='VT'>Vermont</option>
        <option value='VA'>Virginia</option>
        <option value='WA'>Washington</option>
        <option value='WV'>West Virginia</option>
        <option value='WI'>Wisconsin</option>
        <option value='WY'>Wyoming</option>
</select>
<input type='button' id='all_visible' value='Select Visible' />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  Not needed for the bounty (I'll be awarding it right after this comment) since I see this works, but I'm having trouble with it in JSFiddle... any clue why?  https://jsfiddle.net/myingling/3z6mecq9/2/

Comment: I have made some modification in code. Not sure why it is throwing cloning error in fiddle. Check my updated code in fiddle . https://jsfiddle.net/prathameshk73/pvLex31d/14/

I have commented resultNode$